# adding a numbers to a item from navigation menu

Tags: menus

I search in Internet but i didn't find a good documented way how to add to item from menu a number ,
my current menu is like

```
Item1
Item2
Item3 ,
```

I'm calculating with WP_Query how many post for category i have , and within function to update a specific menu item like :

```
Item1(10) 
Item2(5) 
Item3(20)
```

Thank you a LOT ! :)

i finded a solution , but i don't know how to filter by specific menu , location

> function wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects( $items){
>
> ```
> foreach( $items as $item ){
>
>     if( strtolower($item->title)=='sample page' ){
>         $item->title = $item->title.'(10)';
>     }
> }
> return $items; } add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects' );
> ```

menu i'm creating in admin panel , from Apperance > Menus

Thank you again !

Comment: Can you add more detail to your question?

Comment: In order to get valuable help you have to provide us with your current code. There are multiple ways to generate a list/menu...

Answer (score 0):

You can target the location like this:

```
function wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects( $items, $args ){
    if( $args->theme_location === 'primary' ){
        foreach( $items as $item ){
            if( strtolower( $item->title ) === 'sample page' ){
                $item->title = $item->title . '(10)';
            }
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'wpa_filter_nav_menu_objects', 10, 2 );
```

You can also try `$args->menu_id` if you use that input parameter.

Comment: sorry but $args , i tried but is not working , thank you for help !!!

Comment: ok, but this worked on my install, how do you call wp_nav_menu and what is the theme location?